Canon R6 main dial skipping
My Canon R6 is 3 years old. Recently, the main dial at the top (the one you use with the index finger and control the main settings, e.g. Aperture in Av and Exposure time in Tv) started to skip. Some clicks will register and some won't. I don't see an apparent pattern in which will work and which not.
I've put some contact cleaner spray in it which has helped for a while. I've done this a few times but it keeps coming back and getting worse.
I don't really want to dissasemble a 2k+ camera so I'm considering sending it to Canon for repairs. However they won't give me a price estimate until I send them the camera (50€), and if I refuse, they will charge 38€. This makes sense, but I don't really want to pay for nothing or pay a fortune to fix an issue that is annoying but does not completely prevent me from using my camera.
Do some of you have experience with canon repair service and might have an idea what they could charge me?
Or do you have any other suggestions on how I could fix this issue?
Thanks!

probably an unhelpful comment but €50 sounds like an awful lot to send a camera somewhere. There's no cheaper service available?

Which Canon Service Center covers your local geographic area? They can vary widely from one region to the next.

Depends a lot on the technology used.
IMHO is you can spray cleaner fluid on the contacts of the encoder in a theoretically weather-sealed body then the bad contacts may be the least of your problems.
My hypothesis is that it is an optical one which is being clogged by dust/debris, and adding contact cleaner to the mix may just create clumps of dirt that make the matter worse. Blowing air could dislodge the debris and restore proper function.

That's a good point, I hadn't thought that it could be optical, which would make sense. I've tried blowing air with a rubber blower, I could try with a compressed air can to see if that helps.

Rubber blower should be enough. Compressed air could be a bit brutal.

Canned air leaves residue behind. If you use compressed air, use a source that actually compresses air and then filters it.
